# Keyboard Shortcut to open files in specific relative location in desktop screen

Tags: keyboard

Below is a screenshot of my window desktop
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/686Of.png)

Is there any program or operating system that allows to open 'a file in 2nd in row, 2nd in column from the left-top of the desktop screen' only using keyboard shortcuts?

Thanks.

Comment: No easy solution that I am aware of. Depending on how deep you are willing to dig into various APIs and how comfortable you are with writing code, many possible avenues exist though. The most user-friendly approach would probably be something like using AutoHotkey, a tool / scripting language that can be used to assign various scripts (that you yourself write) to hotkeys, and these can do stuff like automating/simulating mouse events. So you could send a click to the desktop at the desired location using that, but again, one would need to write *some* code for that.

Comment: I know how to use autohotkey, but only the rudimentary basics. Would autohotkey works for that?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use, e.g. `ControlClick` to send a double click directly to a predined spot on the desktop, or even better, get a list of the controls and iterate over them to find the one in the desired position, then use the handle of that as a target (do feel free to browse AHK's documentation). (One can even call e.g. any WinAPI functions using DllCall, so you can hook directly into the OS's input processing if necessary, but the purpose of AHK is exactly to provide a friendlier layer of abstraction above some of the pure WinAPI one would use in, e.g. a C++ program.)